# How to avoid duplication problem in seo when create a mobile version of asp.net webpage?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, asp.net

I want to create a mobile version of an existing desktop page. I made copy of my pages and used this code for detecting mobile device :

```
 public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true" ) 
    {
        Response.Redirect(@"~/Content/PageXmobile.aspx");
    }
    else 
    {
        Response.Redirect("PageX.aspx");
    }
}
```

PageXmobile.aspx is a copy of PageX.aspx except that PageXmobile.aspx  is formatted for mobile device but the content is the same on both pages.
How to solve this duplication issue?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use canonical meta tags or HTTP headers.

Add the following meta tag within both pages and point it to the desktop or primary version:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/article-page" />
```

You can also send the following HTTP Header along with the request as an alternate way of providing the canonical page:

```
Link: <http://www.example.com/article-page>; rel="canonical"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the mobile site is not placed on a subdirectory or if there's no mobile counterpart page (`example.com/page1.asp /` `m.example.com/page1.asp`), no need to use the `<link rel="canonical" href="https://m.example.com/page1.asp"/>`.

If they are separate pages, use the `rel="canonical"` attribute and don't forget to add mirror or copy the same meta title and description from the main website to the mobile site.